# Android function helper class

Tags: android

I've been trying to find a tutorial or example on creating Helper class. The only thing that i keep running across is tutorials on Database Helpers. What I'm wanting to do is instead of using repetitive functions or statements etc... i tried to make a helper class to contain he repetitive code but for some reason i can not get it to work. Heres a quick example how/what i am trying to do.

**Helper Class**

```
 public class Helper extends Activity {

    Context ctx;
    static SharedPreferences settings;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    public static final String PREF = "PrefTest";
    static boolean c;
    static int B;
    static String A, a, b, C, D, E, F;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF,MODE_PRIVATE);         
        edit = settings.edit(); 
    }
    public static String userId() {     
        a = settings.getString("Phone", "");
        return a;
    }

    public static String pwd(){
        b = settings.getString("pwd", "");
        return b;
    }

    public static boolean lock(){
        c = settings.getBoolean("pwd", false);
        return c;
    }   
    public static String version(Context ctx) {
        A = ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.version);
        return A;
    }   
    public static void saveUser(String user){
        if(user == null || user == ""){
            edit.putString("Phone", "User N/A");
            edit.commit();
        }else{
            edit.putString("Phone", user);
            edit.commit();
        }       
    } 
    public static void savePwd(String D){
        if(D == null || D ==""){
            edit.putString("pwd",D);
            edit.commit();
        }else{
            edit.putString("pwd",Error.validate(D + userId()));
            edit.commit();
        }       
    }
    public static void saveLock(boolean lock) {
        if (lock){
            edit.putBoolean("Locked", true);
            edit.commit();
        }else{
            edit.putBoolean("Locked", false);
            edit.commit();
        }
    }
    public static int passwordCheck() {
        if (pwd() == null || pwd() == "") {
            B = 0;
        } else {
            B = 1;
        }
        return B;
    }
    public static int phoneCheck() {
        if (userId() == null || userId() == "") {
            B = 0; 
        } else {
            B = 1;
        }
        return B;
    }
    public static int lockCheck() {
        if (lock()) {
            B = 1; 
        } else {
            B = 0;
        }
        return B;
    }
}
```

now when i call :

```
int ab = Helper.phoneCheck();
        if(ab == 0){
            try{
                Helper.saveUser("TestUser");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

it crashes the app, been working on trying to figure out why and i keep running into dead ends and now seeing if someone might be able to help me out with this

**LogCat**

```
05-30 01:25:11.067: D/dalvikvm(1411): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 43K, 53% free 2551K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 125ms
05-30 01:25:11.237: D/AndroidRuntime(1411): Shutting down VM
05-30 01:25:11.237: W/dalvikvm(1411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.prefapp/com.test.prefapp.StartUp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.test.prefapp.Helper.userId(Helper.java:51)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.test.prefapp.Helper.phoneCheck(Helper.java:194)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.test.prefapp.StartUp.onCreate(StartUp.java:44)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-30 01:25:11.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.test.prefapp.Helper.userId(Helper.java:51) It looks like your user id is null for some reason.

Comment: I'm wondering if its because i have the functions outside the oncreate method

Comment: Than comment this and see what happens, maybe the user ID is const so the compiler decides to set this data at program start, also what exactly is line 51 in helper.java class?

Comment: commenting out the line int ab it loads up with out crashing and even tried renaming the function,, but here is the original line 51 `a = settings.getString("Phone", "");`

Comment: try adding if settings != null in userId function if it works, you need to find our why your settings are not loaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two Activities:  Helper and Startup.
And it seems you are calling Helper.phoneCheck from Startup.onCreate.
In Helper.onCreate(), you are initializing settings:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF,MODE_PRIVATE);         
        edit = settings.edit(); 
   }
```

I suspect that when the android framework calls Startup.onCreate, Helper activity has not yet been started.  Thus, its Helper.onCreate was not called and settings would not have been initialized yet.

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can guess one possible solution. How about change Startup so that it extends from Helper, instead of Activity, like so?

```
public class Startup extends Helper {

    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();  // This will initialize Helper.settings
       ...
       int ab = Helper.phoneCheck();

    }
}
```

In this way, you can guarantee that Helper.settings will be initialized by the time you use it.  Also, other activities can extend Helper too and reuse its methods.

Comment: Awesome,,,, thank you so much! i didn't even think of doing that at all... it works perfectly now how i was wanting it to. why is it always the simplest things that stump me. lol thanks again for your help